# Kubernetes pods are pending not active

Tags: kubernetes, kube-scheduler

If I run this:

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
```

I get this output:

```
NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-6fdd4f6856-6bl64                0/1       Pending   0          1h
coredns-6fdd4f6856-xgrbm                0/1       Pending   0          1h
kubernetes-dashboard-65c76f6c97-c69jg   0/1       Pending   0          13m
```

supposedly I need a kubernetes scheduler in order to actually launch containers? Does anyone know how to initiate a kube-scheduler?

Comment: How many nodes are in your cluster? If you only have one node, you must taint it so pods can run on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than a Kubernetes scheduler issue, it looks like it's more about not having enough resources on your nodes (or no nodes at all) in your cluster to schedule any workloads. You can check your nodes with:

```
$ kubectl get nodes
```

Also, you are not likely able to see any control plane resource on the `kube-system` namespace because you may be using managed services like [EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/) or [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/).

Comment: yeah there was a mismatch between the cloudformation stack and the eks cluster